# Movie where an American is forced to move to England

Tags: identify-this-movie

I remember a movie where a privileged Californian child who's mother has died is forced to go to school in an all-girls private school in England. She really dislikes that school and is bullied by a gang of three girls. She starts to engage in the school's lacrosse team and eventually replaces one of the bullies in the team. To get revenge, the bully steals the American's special lighter that she got from her dead mom and sets the kitchen on fire, trying to frame the American. It succeeds and the school holds a trial to decide what will happen to the girl. At the trial, one of her dorm mates remembers something and shows that it was actually the bully who started the fire (I don't remember how she proves this). The bully is expelled and the movie skips ahead to the end of term where when her father comes to pick her up, she finds a picture of her mother as part of the school lacrosse team.

Non-plot released details:

- looked like it was released in the early 2000s to late 1990s
- colour
- originally in English

I hope that that's enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [***Wild Child***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1024255/) (2008) starring Emma Roberts.

> Since Malibu brat Poppy Moore's **mom passed away**, she has pushed her rich, usually absent dad Gerry shamelessly. When his patience wears out, she's shipped off to her mother's former **English boarding school for girls**, Abbey Mount.
>
> On her first day she makes enemies of most dorm mates, especially dominant **lacrosse** school captain Harriet, and the school's principal Mrs. Kingsley. Unwilling to accept the strict regime, she decides to misbehave and take the blame for everyone until she's dismissed. The school only appealing feature for her is Kingsley's dashing son Freddie. When the dream prince transfers his favor from ambitious, uptight Harriet to unruly Poppy, that changes everything